# Adapting BFS to target multiple values

Tags: python, tree, artificial-intelligence, breadth-first-search

i have the  following function program.the function BFS display a path from node to target/goal.how can i modify fuction BFS so that instead of taking a single character as a target,it
should accept a list of characters.

```
# tree stored as a dictionary (parent: [children])
simpletree = {'a':  ['b', 'c'],
              'b':  ['d','e', 'f'],
              'c':  ['g', 'h', 'i','j'],
              'd':  ['k', 'l'],
              'e':  ['m'],
              'g':  ['n'],
              'i':  ['o'],
              'j':  ['p'],
              'o':  ['z']}

def Successors(node,dictionarytree):

    children=dictionarytree[node]#extracting the children of a node

    for child in children:#i get the children using a for loop and  yield
             yield child




# Breadth-First search of a dictionary tree
def BFS(nodelist,target,dictionarytree):
    print "Nodelist:",nodelist
    childlist=[]
    # iterate over all the nodes in parentlist
    for parent in nodelist:

        # if the node is the target
        if parent[-1]==target:
            return parent
        # check if the node has children    
        if dictionarytree.has_key(parent[-1]):#check if the key exists in the  dictionary

            # loop through children and return children
             for child in Successors(parent[-1],dictionarytree): 
                    print child
                    childpath=parent+(child,)#add the targert to the childpath


                    childlist.append(childpath)
                    print "childpath",childpath
    # if there are children, progress to the next level of the tree
    if len(childlist) != 0:
        return BFS(childlist,target,dictionarytree)
    else:
        return None

node='a'
goal='z'
print simpletree
print BFS([(node,)],goal,simpletree)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm, BFS is not really designed to have multiple target endings. You couldn't really call it BFS after the monkeying around.  If you're really interested in that you could always draw it out and see what happens if you follow the algorithm mentally. But you'd need to keep track of which path for which target. I don't think it would help all that much.

Personally, since this looks like it's for school, I'd just iterate over the list of characters in another function and and store the values. You'll need to edit your BFS function to return the path rather than printing it though.

```
def multipleBFSRuns(listOfChars):
  values=[]
  for x in listOfChars:
     values.append(BFS([(node,)],x,simpletree))
  return values
```